# how to update Readme.md vscode extension in vscodemarketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I cant update the vscode extension Readme file after publishing.
Can someone help me how to update the Readme.md in vscode marketplace?

Comment: You have to publish a new version of your extension.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it or not. But you can add to your extension `homepage` attribute at `package.json` file and set its value to link of your GitHub README file.

```json
{
    ...
    "homepage": "https://github.com/your/github/link/README.md",
    ...
}
```

and when you update README file then update your package at marketplace using `vsce publish` it will update README at marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, I've made some changes on my readme file and now I can't just update it to the vscode marketplace... I think the only way then is unpublish the extension and publish again to write the description again.

Comment: I have never had to unpublish an extension to change any file, including `README.md`.  But you do have to update the package.json version number, then `vsce package` and then `vsce publish` and then wait a bit for it to be updated in the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

You can also update your extension through the section [Manage Publishers & Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/) in the VS Marketplace website - you just have to click on the meatballs menu on the left of the current version of your extension and then click **Update**, it will ask you to manually insert an already packaged **vsix** file - It basically does the same thing as `vsce publish`.